# Nested RecyclerViews, internal recycler not displaying

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested

I have an app which sends pictures to our server and receives information back of what the server has identified. Sometimes the server identifies nothing (not an interesting case) sometimes one thing, sometimes more than one thing.

So the data I have to show in a list (RecyclerView) is a photo (plus timestamp) then one or more "things" the server Identified.

My data structure looks like this:

```
List<List<Thing>> masterList;
```

So I have a RecyclerView with with 2 possible items - either a single-Thing item - where I show the picture, time, and Thing info or a multi-Thing item where I show the picture, timestamp and a list of Things.

Here's the higher level Adapter

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<List<Thing>> resultList;
private Context context;

public ResultsAdapter(List<List<Thing>> resultList) {
    this.resultList = resultList;
}

@Override
@NonNull
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0: // regular single thing card
        {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thing_item, parent, false);

            holder =  new ResultsHolder(itemView, listener);
            break;
        }
        default: // multi thing card
        {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compound_item, parent, false);

            holder =  new MultiThingResultsHolder(itemView, listener);
            break;
        }
    }

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();

    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0: // regular single thing card
        {
            ResultsHolder holder = (ResultsHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.time.setText(resultList.get(position).get(0).getTime());

            if (resultList.get(position).get(0).getImage() != null) {
                File thumbnailFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), resultList.get(position).get(0).getImage());
                holder.thumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(thumbnailFile));
            }

        holder.amount.setText(res.getString(R.string.format_blahs, resultList.get(position).get(0).getAmount()));
        .
        .
        .
        .
            break;
        }
        case 2: // multi thing card
        {
            MultiResultsHolder holder = (MultiResultsHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.time.setText(resultList.get(position).get(0).getTime());
            if (resultList.get(position).get(0).getImage() != null) {
                File thumbnailFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), resultList.get(position).get(0).getImage());
                holder.thumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(thumbnailFile));
            }

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            holder.list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            List<Thing> subThingList =  resultList.get(position);

            MultiResultsAdapter adapter = new MultiResultsAdapter(subThingList, subListener, position);
            holder.list.setAdapter(adapter);


            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (resultList.get(position).size() == 1) {
        // this is a simple item
        return 0;
    }
    // if we got here it's a multithing item
    return 1;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

public class ResultsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    private ImageView deleteX;
    public TextView time;
    private ImageView thumbnail;
    private TextView amount;
    .
    .
    .
    .


    private ResultsHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        deleteX = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        deleteX.setOnClickListener(this);
        time = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        amount = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }

}

private class MultiResultsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView thumbnail;
    public TextView time;
    public RecyclerView list;

    private MultiResultsHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        time = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        list = view.findViewById(R.id.list); // <-- the inner Recycler
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }

}

}
```

So then I have an Inner Adapter which works on a simple `List<Thing>`

```
public class MultiResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MultiResultsAdapter.MultiResultsHolder> {

    private List<Thing> thingList;
    private Context context;

    public MultiResultsAdapter(List<Thing> thingList) {
        this.thingList = thingList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MultiResultsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        context = parent.getContext();

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_sub_item, parent, false);

        return new MultiResultsHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MultiResultsHolder holder, int position) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        holder.amount.setText(res.getString(R.string.format_blah, thingList.get(position).getAmount()));
                     .
        .
        .
        .

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return thingList.size();
    }

    public class MultiResultsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView deleteX;
        private TextView amount;
        private TextView fatAmount;
        .    
        .    
        .    
        .    
        private MultiResultsHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            deleteX = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
            deleteX.setOnClickListener(this);
            amount = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
            .
            .
            .
        }

    }

}
```

So - when run, the Single-thing items show up just fine. The Multi-thing items show up with the top part (which is a picture and a time stamp and enough size set aside for the rest of the list (however many items are in it) but the rest is blank. The code for The internal second adapter is being called and I can see that the `onBindViewHolder` is inserting correct values for all the sub items, but they do not show up!

There's just a big item with mostly white space.

Single thing items before and after are just fine, the general scrolling is fine.

I saw an SO answer which suggested I use a CustomLinearLayoutManager for the inner RecyclerView, like this one [here](https://gist.github.com/IgorGanapolsky/348f2fdd56458426710459012aefe210). It did not help, but I saw an interesting Exception - when trying to measure the height of the items the call to `recycler.getViewForPosition(0)` gives an out of bounds exception because somehow the RecycleView.Recycler doesn't know there are any items in the list.I thought this might be a clue, but I don't know how to use it to help

Any ideas out there?

Comment: try to look at this https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/wiki/Quick-start-with-Composite-Items

Comment: Thanks @Vitaly it was a dumb mistake of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow - another doozy  -turns out that I didn't make the Linear layout for my compound item into "orientation:vertical" - and that was what screwed me up - well. this fixes that